# How to map self referencing data to mvc catch all route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm having a problem devising a scheme to map requests to a MVC catch all route to a self referencing table. The data model is simple, it is a poco class that looks like this:

```
    public class Category
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Int32 CategoryId {get; set;}
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Category ParentCategory { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> SubCategories { get; set; }

    public Category()
    {
        SubCategories = new List<Category>();
    }
}
```

I have a SQL Stored Procedure that I'm using to join everything together:

```
CREATE PROC GetSubCategories
(@categoryid int)
AS
BEGIN
WITH cats AS
    (
    SELECT c1.*
    FROM Categories c1
    WHERE CategoryId = @categoryid
    UNION all
    SELECT c2.*
    FROM cats join Categories c2 on cats.CategoryId = c2.ParentCategoryId
    )
    SELECT * FROM cats WHERE CategoryId != @categoryid
END
```

In my controller I load up the entire object graph with a call to the sproc:

```
_map = _context.Database.SqlQuery<Category>("exec GetSubCategories @catId", new SqlParameter("@catId", 1))
            .ToList();
```

So now when the controller is invoked, I receive a string (as expected) such as books/fiction or books/nonfiction and I want to map the passed parameters to the in memory object graph that I loaded above.

So I split the string on the '/' separator and then started writing a brute force loop of finding the first part of the url (book) and then looking at the children of it to see if it contains the the next part of the url requested and so on.

What I am building, if it helps, is a system that ends up being a hierarchy of things: categories for books in this example, but could just as easily be locations in the world, etc. The situation is that there can be multiple root nodes, each node can any number of children, and the depth can be arbitrary. Very much like a file system.

Comment: Can you post your controller action code please?

Comment: I have not written the action method yet... that is where I felt like I was going off the rails and not really sure what implementation makes sense. I feel like I was building a bridge and the guys doing the measuring on each end were off so we can't meet in the middle. The controller is simple, it inherits from the base controller, I have a private field for my database context that I initialize as described earlier and the Index method which takes a single String parameter.